# Gridview adapter different behavior on landscape

Tags: android, gridview, android-adapter, android-gridview

i have gridview with 8 items in 4x2 grid. 
Here is my adapter code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CustomCell v;
    Log.d("position: ", " " + position + " " + convertView);

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        switch (position){
            case 3:
                v = new CustomCellExercise(mContext);
                break;
            case 5:
                v = new CustomCellDrink(mContext);
                break;
            case 7:
                v = new CustomCellSleep(mContext);
                break;
            default:
                v = new CustomCell(mContext);
                break;
        }

    }
    else{
        v = (CustomCell)convertView;
    } 

    //Some text and color settings

    return v;
}
```

When i use it on portrait screen it works fine and last item have class "CustomCellSleep". However when i switch screen to landscape mode, adapter never step to "case 7" and last item have "CustomCell" class. I use this solution because, Exercise,Drink and Sleep cells have different functionality and override method from CustomCell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to intilaize the convertView every time ,,,
thats mean don't use

```
if(convertView == null){

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but i think it isn't good for performance when you don't recycle view. Hovewer if i don't find another solution i use this.